# React Developer Tools wont appear in Chrome

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

I have installed Chrome Developer Tools in my Chrome browser

[image]

But when I open the developer tools, it is nowhere to be seen

[image]

I thought it might be here, but it is not either.

[image]

I need them badly. Can anyone help me figure out why I cannot see them?

**FYI**

This is my software versions:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are in an incognito window? If so, try to toggle the "Allow in Incognito" in the add-on settings.